# How to Setup the Workspace for Mavensmate

Tags: mavensmate

I've tried like they mentioned on GitHub. I am not able to set up the workspace for my work laptop. The error is says:

> Your [mm_workspace] setting is not configured properly. Please ensure any locations specified in mm_workspace exist on the system, then try your operation again.

I created the folder on my desktop called MavensMate. I installed Package Control and I set up the "mm_workspace" to:

```
"/Users/oyl956/Desktop/workspaces/mavensmate"
```

Comment: what is your OS version. OSX or windows

Comment: Could you give a little more information? Where exactly have you set the workspace? What code have you written to define it? Where have you defined it? What version of Mavensmate are you running? As @Himanshu says, what OS are you using?

Comment: I AM USING THE MAC OS I created the folder on my desktop like mavensmate.I installed the package control.I set up the workspace like "mm_workspace" : "/Users/oyl956/Desktop/workspaces/mavensmate",

Comment: when i am opening the new project like it i showing the error like as Your [mm_workspace] setting is not configured properly. Please ensure any locations specified in mm_workspace exist on the system, then try your operation again.

Comment: @ashok can you confirm that you have setup path in Default setting instead of user?

Comment: What version of MM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in a comment you did the following:

> I set up the workspace like "mm_workspace" : "/Users/oyl956/Desktop/workspaces/mavensmate"

I believe (but could be wrong on this) it's defined in JSON and anything past a "/" is escaped meaning you have to escape the "/" so that "/" can be read.

Assuming that directory exists, try setting the workspace to:

```
//Users//oyl956//Desktop//workspaces//mavensmate
```

Assuming you're using Sublime text, I believe there's two documents to edit: user and default. But these only have one `mm_workspace` 'nodes' in each file. However, this escaping rule should be applied to other text-editors too, like Atom.io.

Comment: I tested with // but it didn't work. It seems like he is missing the path. @Ashok can you confirm that your path exist?

Comment: thanks POEt,Himashu.I set up the workspace in the settings user but still i am not able to open the project.I set the the workspace as 
       "mm_workspace" :"//Users/oyl956//Desktop//workspaces//mavensmate" now i am getting the error as Your [mm_workspace] property is not set. Open 'MavensMate > Settings > User' or press 'Cmd+Shift+,' and set this property to the full path of your workspace. Thx!

Comment: I created the mavensmate folder on desktop.then I added this path in the workspace mentioned above.Is my path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps

1. go to Mavensmate0-> Settings->user

[image]

2. set the mm_workspace parameter with `/Users/oyl956/Desktop/workspaces/mavensmate`

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this addresses his problem? He said in his question he's already set the "mm_workspace" so he must know where that is.

Comment: @Poet You are write mate. I completely missed that comment otherwise i wouldn't waste time to take screenshot :)

but my screenshot can be helpful for the person who missed that steps. ;)

Comment: I also made the mistake of assuming he's using Sublime text as well. :) It's probably a educated assumption but he could be using another editor like Atom. I clarified that in my answer.